# ImportError: No module named allauth error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, pycharm

I'm a starter in python django. I've used social authentication in my application and now when i had to switch my laptop, I run my application it says **ImportError: No module named allauth**.

I've tried the solutions available already on this site but the problem is it gives this error on each and every command i try to run.

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.1.2\bin\runnerw.exe" 
C:\Python27\python.exe D:/maryam/storefront/storefront/manage.py runserver 
8000
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x03EBD530>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226,    in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in 
inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, 
in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, 
in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in 
populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in 
create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name) 
ImportError: No module named allauth
a
```

Comment: is the module installed? If not, add the code to your question to see what may be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the allauth module using pip.

Please check this link for more details: http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 5):

to install allauth with pip, type this command
`pip install django-allauth`