# After i have installed allauth for django ModuleNotFoundError while migrating

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-allauth

**I have installed django-allauth by pip install django-allauth. movies is the name of my app**

[image: error image]

Comment: I suspect that you do not have a comma after `'movies'` in your INSTALLED_APPS setting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named allauth error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142596/importerror-no-module-named-allauth-error)

Comment: Share you setting.py file code

Answer (score 0):

Did you add allauth as an active application to your settings file?